# How to run a function on the first x elements, then another x and another until all elements have been clicked

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of Javascript code which clicks on a specific element. The code is helpful in opening accordions. However, I don't wish to put unnecessary load on the server. I was wondering if there is a way I can click the first x elements then wait for example 5 seconds, then click on the second lot of the same element, like that until all have been clicked. So basically doing the clicking in batches and waiting for x seconds before clicked the next batch.

The code I have so far:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  setTimeout(
    function myFunction() {
const matchBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.classname')
let nextClickIn = 0;
let delay = 500;
matchBtns.forEach((matchbtn) => {
    setTimeout(() => {matchbtn.click()}, nextClickIn)
    nextClickIn += delay
})
}
,0);
})
```

The delay I have there is the delay between clicking elements. So now I am trying to achieve clicks between a batch of clicks.

Thanks.

Comment: "However, I don't wish to put unnecessary load on the server." - javascript is executed in the visitor's browser, not on the server.

Comment: Why do you need to click on the actual buttons? Just add CSS classes with javascript to open all panels in the accordion. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: I am visiting multiple pages at a time so as much as javascript is loaded on the client side, i think that also contributes. Anyway, I am new to javascript but I'll surely try the suggestion which is interesting.

Comment: It's using ajax to fetch data from the server. So the data is not pre-stored there as the  w3schools example given. So CSS won't likely be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to each button.

If they have their own event listeners then add the id and select them to add the event listener.

Also 500 is half a seconds 5000 is 5 seconds.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  setTimeout(function myFunction() {
    const matchBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.classname');
    matchBtns.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log('Yes');
      });
    });
    let nextClickIn = 0;
    let delay = 500;
    matchBtns.forEach((matchbtn) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        matchbtn.click();
      }, nextClickIn);
      nextClickIn += delay;
    });
  }, 0);
});
```

Comment: I need the code I gave to run for a specific number of .classname elements. Then wait for 5000 then run for the next x again until all are done. Tried the code you gave but it doesn't work like that yet.